# Having an issue with randomization in Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so i've been trying to make it so that every time the user sends a message there's a 50/50 chance that the bot reacts with an emoji, however the number is only picked every time i restart the bot. any ideas on how i can make it pick the number every time the command is triggered?

i tried to use `setInterval` but that didn't work so idk

here code;

```
const userID = "user id"
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if(random === 1) {
    if(message.author.id === userID) {
      message.react('emoji');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply, define the `random` variable inside the `messageCreate` event.

Example:

```js
const userID = "user id";

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  if (random === 1) {
    if (message.author.id === userID) {
      message.react('emoji');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define `random` inside of the `messageCreate` event it means that a new random number is generated each time the even is called.

```js
const userID = "user id"

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
  if(random === 1) {
    if(message.author.id === userID) {
      message.react('emoji');
    }
  }
});
```

As Tyler2P has already shown an example, just wanted to explain why this works.
Thanks